# Adjust canvas size relative to text size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

In My **AngularJS** application, I have to generate text image and for that, I'm using hidden canvas element and then append the image value to the `img` tag.

The font size of the text can be changed and image data should update simultaneously.

For that, I have created a javascript function

```
$scope.updateTextLogo = function() {

        // Update canvas element
        var canvas = $scope.canvas;
        var ctx = canvas.ctx;
        var text = $scope.text;

        // Set canvas
        ctx.canvas.width = ctx.measureText(text.text).width;

        var font_string = '';
        // Add font size
        font_string += ' ' + text.size + 'px';

        ctx.font = font_string;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ff00ff';
        ctx.fillText(logoText.text, 0, 10);

        // Convert data to image
        var imageElement = canvas.image;
        imageElement.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();

        document.getElementById('logoTextImgContainer').appendChild(imageElement);
    };
```

and calling the function from the slider

```
<slider class="slider-parent" ng-model="text.size" min="10" step="1" max="50" value="14" ng-change="updateTextLogo();"></slider>
```

Everything is working fine, but the canvas size (width and height) is fixed on changing the size of the font. The output is like

[image]

*Text content is **Hello World** and font size is **21px**. Also, see the long height (white space) under the text.*

1. I want the canvas height to be the height of the text.
2. Also, the width of the canvas to be the width of the text.

**How can I change the canvas size dynamically with a change in text length or size?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used https://github.com/vincent7128/text-image plugin to generate an image from the text.

The plugin also supports customization and special characters.